# Not able to get pixel perfect heights cross-browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have Firefox and Chrome lined up side by side. I have an h1 element with no vertical padding or no vertical margin on a text item that uses a Web Font. I am getting a one pixel difference. If I look at the Computed info in firefox and also in chrome, both are computed at 56px, but visually there is some padding on both of which firefox is 1 pixel extra. Any ideas on how to fix this? Unable to upload a photo.

Comment: You're going to have to supply us code or something. (Upload a photo to imgur or something)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to provide us with some image or something so we can better assist you.
But try using Normalize.css

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: I have normalize already set up. Here is a simplified version that you can preview in a browser: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
<style type="text/css">
 * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
 }
 body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Test Text</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. I added a 1px margin top and it aligned correctly on both Chrome, and FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to get into it, there's a host of direct FF only CSS calls like you use to target IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

There's one for margin and padding that may work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
* {margin: 0;padding: 0}
body,html {height: 100%;width: 100%}
   </style>
```

add this to your style and all should go well

Comment: Already have that set up. Here is a simplified version: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
<style type="text/css">
 * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
 }
 body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Test Text</h1>
</body>
</html>